# Place string variable and Send Keys in Excel Alert Message

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I am writing a macro in excel 2016 to manipulate data in a workbook that is linked to a SQL server. I need to refresh all data in a workbook before using the data. However a an inputbox appears when "Refresh All" (located in the Data Tab) asking me for a password. I want the code to flow as follows.

```
'Prompt opens
SendKeys("foobar")
SendKeys("{ENTER}")
```

When I try to SendKeys to the prompt the code stops executing, and will not resume until i manually type in the password and hit enter. How can i send a string to this prompt, as well as send keys to enter the string?

Image: [image: Input Prompt]

Comment: A password for *what*?  (ie., a file, a server, user)  Perhaps a screenshot of the dialog box would be helpful.  Certain types of dialogs are specifically designed in such a way that they can't be defeated programmatically ... I'm not sure if this one, but whatever it is, should have an alternate way of "remembering" the password instead of having to enter it manually.

Comment: The image has been attached to the original question.

Comment: Are all those fields blank every time or just the password?  Has this server connection been setup as an ODBC Data Source?  (`Start` > `ODBC` > check under `User`/`System`/`File DSN` tabs...  if you find the connection, see if you an modify the connection to save the password, etc)

Comment: The Server and Login ID are already filled when the prompt appears. I checked my ODBCs and the connection is not set up as a Data Source. However, the check box Use Trusted Connection will also refresh the data if it is checked.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that last part

Comment: Sorry about that. I meant to throw in the check box comment as a random side note in case that piece of info would be relevant.

Comment: How did you **create** this link in the first place? (or was it, by chance, created by someone else?)

Comment: It was created by someone else. I'm not sure how they created the link, but it was most likely linked through software program internal to my company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically this is not an answer to your *question*, but it is a possible solution to your *problem*! (ie., [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378))  Rather than putting focus on a *workaround* to solve your issue of SQL Server not remembering the password, we could instead focus on the problem *itself*.

Without having more information in your question (such as, "How did you create this link in the first place?"), I will assume that Excel is using an [ODBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity) [DSN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/966849/what-is-a-dsn-data-source-name) to connect.  (At some point, someone had to "tell" Excel the name of the Server and Login ID, and there are only so many ways to do that.)

- Hit the <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>Windows Key and type `odbc`.
- If you're running a 64-bit system you should have two relevant options:

  [image: odbc]
- Open both of these to to check 3 places in each:

[image: img]

If there are any items listed besides those shown in the image, they can be **double-clicked** to investigate whether this could be the source of the SQL Server Login Info.

---

If there is definitely not a related ODBC DSN here then the next thing to check is data connections within Excel in `Data` > `Queries & Connections`.

---

### More Information:

- Wikipedia : [**Open Database Connectivity (ODBC)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity)
- Microsoft : [**What is a DSN (Data Source Name)?**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/966849/what-is-a-dsn-data-source-name)
- Microsoft : [**Microsoft SQL Server ODBC DSN Configuration**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn170503(v=vs.85).aspx)